# I am not able to send Additional Form Data with the DropZone File Upload

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

This is the dropzone code I am executing

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone",
    {
        url: "/opd/addMedicalRecord",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        parallelUploads: 20,
        uploadMultiple: 20,
        maxFiles: 20,
        paramName: 'file',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        init: function()
            {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("button#modal_addRecord")
                myDropzone = this; // closure
                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function()
                    {
                        myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
                        alert("Called Process Queue");
                    });
                // You might want to show the submit button only when 
                // files are dropped here:
                this.on("addedfile", function()
                    {
                        // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
                        //  alert("Called Added File");
                    });
                this.on('uploadprogress', function(file, progress, bytesSent, formData)
                    {
                        formData.append('reportType', $('input[name=modal_reportType]:checked', 'div#addNewReport').val());
                        formData.append('reportTitle', $("#modal_reportTitle").val());
                        formData.append('reportInvestigationDate', $("#modal_investigationDate").val());
                        formData.append('reportNote', $("#modal_notes").val());

                        // console.log('File is ' + file);
                        // console.log('Progress is ' + file.upload.progress);
                        // console.log('Size is ' + file.upload.bytesSent);
                        // $("#uploadProgress").css("width",Math.ceil(file.upload.progress) + "%");
                    });

                this.on('complete',function(file)
                    {
                        // $("#full").modal('hide');
                        $("#uploadProgress").css("width","0%");
                        myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
                    });
            }
    });
```

This is my Html Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="full" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addNewReport" onSubmit="return false;">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header green-modal">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add new report for Abhishek Bharambe</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{-- <form onSubmit="return false;" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addNewReport"> --}}
                    <div class="row mt-15"> {{-- Report Type--}}
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-radios">
                                <label>Select Report Type</label>
                                <div class="md-radio-inline">
                                    <div id="r_labreports_r_a" class="md-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="modal_labReports" name="modal_reportType" value="lab" class="md-radiobtn">
                                        <label for="modal_labReports"> <span class="inc"></span> <span class="check"></span> <span class="box"></span> Lab Reports </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="r_imaging_r_a" class="md-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="modal_labImaging" name="modal_reportType" value="image" class="md-radiobtn">
                                        <label for="modal_labImaging"> <span class="inc"></span> <span class="check"></span> <span class="box"></span> Imaging </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-15"> {{-- Report Title--}}
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left capsule-lightblue">
                                    <i class="fa fa-hospital-o blue-icon-font"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" class="typeahead-newrecord form-control input-circle-right" id="modal_reportTitle" placeholder="Enter Report Title" name="reportTitle">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-15">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="5pw input-group-addon input-circle-left capsule-lightblue">
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar blue-icon-font"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input name="date" class="pw100 input-circle-right form-control form-control-inline input-medium date-picker" form-input size="16" type="text" id="modal_investigationDate" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" placeholder="Date of Investigation (Optional)" /> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-25">
                        <form class="dropzone dropzone-file-area" multiple name="file[]" id="my-dropzone" accept=accept="image/*, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx" style="width: 500px; margin-top: 50px;">
                            <h3 class="sbold">Drop Report related files here or click to upload</h3>
                            <p> You can upload images (.jpg, .jpeg, .png) or documents (.pdf, .docx, .doc, .xls, .xlsx) of the report. </p>
                        </form>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%" id="uploadProgress">
                                    <span class="sr-only"> 0% Uploaded </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="btn hide" id="mbtn">Upload</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">{{--Notes--}}
                        <div style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="modal_notes" rows="2" cols="2" name="modal_notes"></textarea>
                                <label for="mpdal_notes">Notes</label>
                                <span class="help-block">Additional Notes Here</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- </form> --}}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        {{-- Submit Button --}}
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopad">
                                <button id="modal_addRecord" class="fwb btn btn-circle green-meadow">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Add Record
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopad">
                                <button type="button" class="fwb btn btn-circle btn-outline dark" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I the Laravel Backend Side I am displaying the data to see the response:

```
print_r($request->all());
exit();
```

The problem is that I want to also send the remaining form data with the file upload. In the current situation, there is a successful file upload it is also reaching the server but the remaining form data is not being posted to the server what is the error i am not able to trace it?

While appending the data in the dropzone section it gives an erro like => `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: `uploadMultiple` its a boolean, you should set it to `true`

Comment: still it gives this error => `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `uploadprogress` you should use `sending`  .Dropzone uploadprogress does not take formData. read more [here](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events), look at the event list read what each one does.

Here is an example :

```
myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){...
```

> Edit.

- Sending takes 3 parameters `file, xhr, formData`

Add the sneding line form above, then your formData.... and then pu this to process the Queue `myDropzone.processQueue();`

Comment: But, i am using `this.on('uploadprogress', function(file, progress, bytesSent, formData)` should i replace `uploadprogress` with `sending` will it work?

Comment: Still giving an error of `Cannot read property 'append' of undefined`

Comment: why you use this? `myDropzone = this;`  just replace everywhere you have  `this` with `myDropzone ` and remove that line

Comment: even done your way still same error `Cannot read property 'append' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I use vue2-dropzone 3.0.3 and below is my code
On vuejs template:

```
<vue-dropzone :options="dropzoneOptions">
```

and

```
export default {
....
    dropzoneOptions: { url: this.myUrl, method: 'POST', params: {'userId': 
1, 'userName': 'TranVoNB'}, }
.....
```

(I use `params` to add additional parameters)

and on Laravel controller:

```
$request->get('userId') //TranVoNB
```